# ReadObject() as Generic Type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, task, datacontractjsonserializer

is it possible to do something like this

```
   async Task<T> ProcessRequest<T>() {
     var serializer    = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
     var repositories  = serializer.ReadObject(await streamTask) as T;
     ...
   }
```

Basically, I want to pass the type into my function to serialize like so

```
   ProcessRequest<MyJsonObj>();
```

Edit: nvm, I've solved it. I just needed a break from my code. ;P The compiler was complaining when i as "as T". I've just came back to it and cast it to T and it's working now.

Comment: Why not? Where is the problem you are facing?

Comment: The problem was "as" doesn't have a class type constraint. But it's ok. I've fixed. Thanks for comment though.

Comment: As an option you can use explicit cast operator: 
(T) serializer.ReadObject(...) , which does not require class constraint on the generic method